# How to add Linq to SQL class

Tags: sql, visual-studio, linq

I can't find Linq to SQL class when I tried in my VS2017.
From within a C# application, on the Project menu, click Add New Item, then there is not 'Linq to SQL'.
On Visual C# Items, it only shows
Classes
Class for U-SQL
Forms Blank Content Page Xaml
... and the last item is
WCF Workflow Service.

There is any Setting error on me?
Would you tell me any hint?

Comment: Excuse me. I had a wrong for not set the LINQ to SQL at the first setting for Visual Studio 2017. I amended it and now I can do it for now.

Comment: if this question is no longer needed please delete it.

Answer (score 0):

**First step** - [Missing LINQ to SQL Classes (DBML designer) in Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485881/missing-linq-to-sql-classes-dbml-designer-in-visual-studio-2017-rc)

**Second step** - Go to project properties -> Under Application tab select Target Framework to .NET 4.0 or higher and save.

It resolved my issue, hope it resolves yours too.