# LINQ to SQL - VISUAL STUDIO Community 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2017, dbml

How can i add LINQ to SQL class (.dbml file) to a Visual Studio 2017 Project. I can't find it. even though i added the " Linq to SQL tool "  it in the " Visual Studio Installer " i couldn't find it. Any solutions please ?

Comment: Right click on a folder in your project, then `Add > New Item > Visual C#/VB > Data > Linq to SQL classes`. But it needs to be installed with Visual Studio, it is not installed by default I think.

Comment: I already did that. I installed " Linq to SQL tool " in the " Visual Studio Installer " i restarted my session, but still couldn't find it. isn't there any other way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing LINQ to SQL Classes (DBML designer) in Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485881/missing-linq-to-sql-classes-dbml-designer-in-visual-studio-2017-rc)

Comment: Maybe that will help...

Comment: Thank you @VDWWD, but I already saw that post. We have the same problem,but the answers didn't solve it. if you see the comments in the post you just sent me, there's a guy who had the same problem as me. Even though he reinstalled VStudio with the " Linq to SQL tool " he couldn't find it to add it in the project.

Comment: Is there any other package or tool for VS2017 that can work like "Linq to SQL" ?