# Linq to SQL tools in Visual studio 2022 Community and Pro

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2022

I'm installing Visual studio 2022 (I tried with Community and Pro) in a Windows 11 (virtual machine on macOS - Parallels desktop) but i can't find Linq to SQL Tools under Individual components, Code Tools category.  This option doesn´t appears in order to be checked.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you for your help!

I need to use Linq to SQL Tools to edit a bdml file in a asp.net proyect

Comment: Look for dbml tools?

Comment: Yes! that's what I need edit the model in design view... now I only can see it in xml format.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485881/missing-linq-to-sql-classes-dbml-designer-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/42486050#42486050

Comment: Yes, I have seen those solution suggestions, but in these cases the option to be checked, Installer/Individual components/Linq to SQL Tools under  Code Tools category does appear, but in my case it does not even appear.  This is only in VS 2022

Comment: Having the same problem, did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Nop... I finally had to give up using visual studio on my macbook...apparently it's not available on M1

Comment: I opened a ticket with Microsoft and they said some workloads aren't supported on ARM. I assume you're using ARM since you have an M1, so I guess we're just sunk. What's curious though is that I do have a Windows 11 Insider version where the installation works fine.